# Formatting the Layout of Splitbib category Headings

Tags: bibliographies, splitbib

I am using `splitbib` package to generate multiple bibliographies but for some reason I want to change its outlook a little bit.

To be more specific, I want the categories headings  (like BOOKS and ARTICLE in the below picture) to be left aligned and without the lines above and below the category headings.
[image]

Following is the MWE to generate a sample of `splitbib` bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[export]{splitbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{category}{Books}
\SBentries{B1,B2}
\end{category}
\begin{category}{Articles}
\SBentries{A1}
\end{category}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@BOOK{B1,
  author =       {Author First and Author Second},
  title =        {Title of the first book},
  publisher =    {Demo Publisher ONE},
  year =         {2014}
}
@ARTICLE{A1,
  author =       {Author First Article and Second Author},
  title =        {This is the title of first article},
  journal =      {Name of the Journal},
  year =         {2012},
  volume =       {01},
  number =       {12},
  pages =        {101--114}
}
@BOOK{B2,
  author =       {Second Author Book},
  title =        {This is the title of the second book},
  publisher =    {NHL},
  year =         {2011}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

I want to split the reference of this article of \cite{A1} along with the this book \cite{B2} and this book too \cite{B1}.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't give the output of your image.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Goodness me, I have edited the question and added picture with reference to MWE. Thanks for pointing out this to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own style (but with biblatex it would be more straightforward. E.g. you could use simply `\subsection` which doesn't work here due to hardcoded penalties.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[export]{splitbib}

\makeatletter
\def\NMSB@titlestyle{simple}
\def\NMSB@stylesimple#1#2{\if@nobreak\else\bigskip\fi\textbf{\large #1#2}}
\makeatother
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{category}{Books}
\SBentries{B1,B2}
\end{category}
\begin{category}{Articles}
\SBentries{A1}
\end{category}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@BOOK{B1,
  author =       {Author First and Author Second},
  title =        {Title of the first book},
  publisher =    {Demo Publisher ONE},
  year =         {2014}
}
@ARTICLE{A1,
  author =       {Author First Article and Second Author},
  title =        {This is the title of first article},
  journal =      {Name of the Journal},
  year =         {2012},
  volume =       {01},
  number =       {12},
  pages =        {101--114}
}
@BOOK{B2,
  author =       {Second Author Book},
  title =        {This is the title of the second book},
  publisher =    {NHL},
  year =         {2011}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

I want to split the reference of this article of \cite{A1} along with the this book \cite{B2} and this book too \cite{B1}.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is wonderful and worked perfect as I desired.